# Opencv remove ghosting distortion

Tags: python, opencv

I get a problem when handling images taken from cell phones.

Image sample:
[image]
So, get ghosting especially for the question number area.

I think the reason is a little joggle when press the shutter.

Is there any way to remove the ghosting thus question number area will look more clear?

There is another worse one:
[image]
Actually, I find some image denoising functions like cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(), and it indeed works well upon some images.

Unfortunately, doesn't work for the above two images.

Env: Python3.6.5 Opencv:3.4.0

Thanks.

Wesley

Comment: You are seeing the effect of motion blur. There are some ways to reduce it, for instance: [Motion Deblur Filter](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0-beta/d1/dfd/tutorial_motion_deblur_filter.html).

Comment: @Catree Thanks. I will have a look for details.

Comment: Might be worth educating your users on how to capture good images. This looks taken in very poor lighting causing long exposure time (thus the blur) and it's still quite underexposed.

Comment: @DanMašek Sure, actually, we told them to capture good images. But, for cell phones, especially for Android, there are so many manufactures and phone models with quite different hardware parameters. We should also try our best to handle these images. So, for the second image, it's reasonable to refuse, but for most of users, the first one is acceptable from the human eye side.

Comment: As @Catree suggested, I am trying to use deconvolution to make motion deblur, it does have a little improvement, but not the best. What's more, seems it's hard to dynamically determine the parameters, e.g. SNR, THETA, LEN, according to individual images :-(